# Parsing a single String

Tags: android, parsing, post

This may sound very weird but here it goes.

I have an HTTP Post that goes through perfectly now I get my response and need the value to change.

My response if not valid comes back as `NO`

My response if it has a value will be `YES.50`

How can I take my final result and just get the .50 from it? Possibly replacing the YES with "" or something.

In the end I will have a price value that this needs to subtracted from like a discount code.

My Async Task:

```
public class GetPromoTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private Exception exception;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            String result = null;

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url[0]);
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("promo",userPromo));
            HttpResponse response;
            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = client.execute(post);
                promoBuilder = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(promoBuilder != null){
                result = promoBuilder.toString();
            }else{

            }

            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Log.d(tag,"Result of POST: " + result);
            if(result != null){

            }
```

Any Help Much Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have got your question correctly, you can use

```
if(result.contains("YES"))
   result = result.replaceAll("YES", "");
else
   // response is NO
```

Comment: So simply yet it was never what i thought it would be hahaha